how to generate kotlin.Pair with openapi-generator
I would like to define a requestBody that simply resolves to a kotlin.Pair when generated. I tried the following but with no luck:
requestBody:
  required: true
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          first:
            type: string
          second:
            type: string

Can it be done and if so, how?

A pair of values can be defined like this in OpenAPI, but I'm not sure OpenAPI Generator can translate this into kotlin.Pair. You might need to customize the built-in codegen templates or write your own templates. Or just use a generic object or array instead of a Pair.

I would not do that even if you figure out how, because an openapi-spec should ideally compile to usable code in many languages and they may not have tuples (javascript, java, go...)

I think you got me wrong here. In my opinion this should be possible by configuring the generator, not by stating it in the spec itself. It usually works with importMappings and typeMappings, however it doesn’t work for kotlin.Pair because it has two generic parameters. I could only get it to work with types that have only one generic parameter, e.g. List.
